# bootstrap carousel not working in bootstrap mega menu

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

I am making mega menu, in sub menu I have carousel when I click on carousel next icon it doesn't show next carousel item suddenly sub menu is closed.this thing as also happening with bootstrap tabpanel  Please help me.

```css
 .mega-dropdown {
    position: static !important;
    }
    .mega-dropdown-menu {
    padding: 20px 0px;
    width: 100%;
    box-shadow: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    }
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
  <body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
<div class="navbar-header">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
</div>
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
  <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  

  <li class="dropdown mega-dropdown open"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" aria-expanded="true">Page 1 <span class="caret"></span></a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu mega-dropdown-menu">
   <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
<li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
<li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1" class=""></li>
<li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2" class=""></li>
<li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3" class=""></li>
  </ol>

<!-- Wrapper for slides -->
 
 <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="http://science-all.com/images/wallpapers/free-picture/free-picture-10.jpg" alt="Chania">
    </div>

<div class="item">
  <img src="http://cdn.lightgalleries.net/4bd5ec0f44d0a/images/stock_photography157-2.jpg" alt="Flower">
</div>

<div class="item">
  <img src="http://coachparaempresarias.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/Pareja-Mayor.jpg" alt="Flower">
</div>
  </div>

<!-- Left and right controls -->
 
<a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
         </div>
  </li></ul>
  </div>

</nav>
    </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

JS , CSS & HTML Code

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".dropdown").hover(            
        function() {
            $('.dropdown-menu', this).not('.in .dropdown-menu').stop(true,true).slideDown("400");
            $(this).toggleClass('open');        
        },
        function() {
            $('.dropdown-menu', this).not('.in .dropdown-menu').stop(true,true).slideUp("400");
            $(this).toggleClass('open');       
        }
    );
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', 'sans-serif';
}
.mega-dropdown {
  position: static !important;
}
.mega-dropdown-menu {
    padding: 20px 0px;
    width: 100%;
    box-shadow: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
}
.mega-dropdown-menu > li > ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.mega-dropdown-menu > li > ul > li {
  list-style: none;
}
.mega-dropdown-menu > li > ul > li > a {
  display: block;
  color: #222;
  padding: 3px 5px;
}
.mega-dropdown-menu > li ul > li > a:hover,
.mega-dropdown-menu > li ul > li > a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.mega-dropdown-menu .dropdown-header {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #ff3546;
  padding: 5px 60px 5px 5px;
  line-height: 30px;
}

.carousel-control {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  top: -35px;

}
.left.carousel-control {
  right: 30px;
  left: inherit;
}
.carousel-control .glyphicon-chevron-left, 
.carousel-control .glyphicon-chevron-right {
  font-size: 12px;
  background-color: #fff;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-shadow: none;
  color: #333;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
  <body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      
    
  <li class="dropdown mega-dropdown open"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" aria-expanded="true">Page 1 <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu mega-dropdown-menu">
       <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1" class=""></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2" class=""></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3" class=""></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="http://science-all.com/images/wallpapers/free-picture/free-picture-10.jpg" alt="Chania">
    </div>

    

    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://cdn.lightgalleries.net/4bd5ec0f44d0a/images/stock_photography157-2.jpg" alt="Flower">
    </div>
    </div>
         
         <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: its carousel item working good but when I am clicking at home its also showing sub menu of page 1 carousel. check it.

Comment: Thanks for this Thank u so much :) If I want to use vertical tabpanel at sub menu what should I do? because tabpanel was also not working like my carousel .